# heavy numerical data entry UI pattern?

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile, uwp-xaml

Is there any UWP "pattern" or maybe just some tips for a data entry form that is geared towards allowing the user to enter a series of numerical fields quickly/efficiently?  We are creating a tablet-only app (so WUP may not have been the best choice, but due to circumstances beyond our control we're committed).  There's one form where the user will enter 10-12 numerical values in rapid succession.

Our users will likely use an external keyboard.  I'm a newbie, but am inheriting a fairly functional incomplete application to finish.  We've been throwing around ideas like a number-pad keyboard which is locked visible somehow and/or maybe tabbing through the controls?  Not sure if any of this is possible via UWP. Would appreciate any guidance or reference sites!  I'm sure we're not the only ones working this problem...at least I hope not!

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `TextBox` with `InputScope` set to `Number` to display a numeric on screen keyboard. If your numbers are of known number of digits - you could automatically switch focus once a proper number of digits is entered. You could also provide +/- buttons if the numbers are small. The [`NumericUpDown`](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit/blob/master/WinRTXamlToolkit.Sample/Views/Controls/NumericUpDownTestView.xaml) control in WinRT XAML Toolkit has the +/- buttons and can also change values by sliding up/down or left/right on the entry box. Since we're talking about sliding - the platform's `Slider` control allows you to select values by sliding a slider.